# how to customize the UIImage pickerView in zbar SDK or in zxing sdk?

Tags: iphone, camera, barcode

I am working on barcode reader app which reads barcode and display, its data using zbar Sdk or zxing SDK.
Now client wants to customize the square bracket which appears when camera auto focus the barcode.
How to customize it like this???

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkKQr.png

Thanks